# containerizing a .net c# WPF application with docker

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, docker

I want to deploy a **WPF .Net(Version 4.0, C#)** Application with **Docker** since I need to install multiple hardware related software installed before the program starts. 
And also want to install java before it because there is java program which needs to run inside this c# application.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible?, which I hope 'Yes' on the basis of what I have read
   till now
2. How I can do it.
3. If any other way available for doing it.
4. which would be preferable one.

Any sort of referential link, video that can help me moving. I'll be grateful for this.

Comment: Docker containers are typically headless so it's going to be hard to run any kind of UI application inside them. Am I missing something in what you're asking?

Comment: yeah. you got this. any other way could help me to creating a setup file for this application if you can suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution of requirement at that time by wix (window installer) https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/

with the help of this you can write a xml like code to provide step by step procedures to run and generate a .msi or .exe file.
I hope this will help visitors.

Comment: Accept your answer to close the question once you can.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to run WPF application in docker container (see this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt797650.aspx) for more info):

> You can’t run desktop apps in Docker because there’s no UI integration between the Docker platform and the Windows host. That rules out running Windows Forms or Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) apps in containers

Comment: thanks @ingvar for answering. only a hour ago I gone through this article. if any other way you could suggest me for creating a setups file would be very helpful.